# Scalebox, Parbox, and Page Break

Tags: equations, page-breaking, parbox, scalebox

I have a long equation inside the scalebox. However, I can not force it to break between the pages. The code looks like this:

```
\scalebox{.95}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{align}
bla1 & bla2 \\
bla3 & bla4 \\
bla5 & bla6 \\
\end{align}
}}
```

How is it possible to enforce this code to break between two pages?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. A box is just that: a box.

Comment: @RobtAll, thank you for the comment. Is there an alternative solution? I mean if one wants to scale an equation in such a way that it breaks between the pages, what is the solution then?

Comment: one possible approach is to set `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble, create a group around the display with either braces or `\begingroup ... \endgrouip`, and set the size to `\small` (equivalent of 90% or 9pt) within that group,  i can;t test this just now (no available latex installation), but i can do so tomorrow.  in any case, putting it in a box of any kind will never allow a break.  oh, `\allowdisplaybreaks` and related commands are documented in the `amsmath user's guide (`texdoc amsmath`).

Comment: The `adjustbox` an *experimental* feature to break scaled boxes, but this splits it sometimes between lines, e.g. cut through letters.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a box, you can temporarily set the text size smaller before invocation of the `align`, with the `\allowdisplaybreaks` set. [after posting, I realize that this is precisely what Barbara suggests]

EDITED to insert a `\par` and a minus `\vspace` prior to the font-size change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\textheight4.4in
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
bla1 & bla2 \\
bla3 & bla4 \\
bla5 & bla6 
\end{align}
\lipsum*[4]
{\par\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\parskip\relax}
\small\begin{align}
bla1 & bla2 \\
bla3 & bla4 \\
bla5 & bla6 
\end{align}}\ignorespaces
\lipsum*[4]
{\par\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\parskip\relax}
\scriptsize\begin{align}
bla1 & bla2 \\
bla3 & bla4 \\
bla5 & bla6 
\end{align}}\ignorespaces
\lipsum*[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the only purpose of the text size, so that it visually fits nicely? I assume so. Or, does `\allowdisplaybreaks` expect a text size change, as some kind of signal?

Comment: @RobtAll Text size change here produces smaller results, akin to a `\scalebox`, but without the box.  The completely separate command,  `\allowdisplaybreaks`, allows multi-line equations in the `align` family to break midway, across page boundaries.

Comment: Please, try the same with `\lipsum*` and you’ll see that something needs a fix